# How to use multiple "their" word?

Tags: grammar, determiners, possessive-determiners, distributive-determiners, relative-determiners

How to use multiple "their" word ?

For example, in the sentence "parents and their children are criminals and their accomplices respectively", does the latter word "their" refers to parents or criminals ?

tks in adv
o

Comment: The parents _are_ the criminals so they aren't separate groups.

Comment: It makes no sense as a complete sentence.

Comment: "are criminals and accomplices of criminals".

Answer (score 0):

"Respectively" means that what you stated earlier will be used in the same order. It's wrong to have a second "their" in the first place. This should clear up the problem.
"parents and their children are criminals and accomplices respectively".
Meaning the parents are criminals and their children are accomplices.

Comment: I think the second "their" is OK, it confirms that the children are accomplices of the parents, not accomplices of someone else. Although that would likely be assumed.